# Agumentation of Tabular Dataset

Tags: python, keras, generative-adversarial-network, data-generation

I am trying to increase the size of a numeric dataset that I have been working with. The dataset comprises the columns: **[‘Name’, ‘O3_1hr’, ‘O3_4hr’, ‘O3_8hr’, ‘PM10 1 hr’, ‘PM10’, ‘AQI_O3_1hr’, ‘AQI_O3_4hr’, ‘AQI_PM10’, ‘AQI_Site’, ‘Date’, ‘Time’, ‘Latitude’, Longitude’]**.

Previously, I attempted to use a GAN (Generative Adversarial Network) for data augmentation. The architecture of GAN is:

```
def build_generator(latent_dim):
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=latent_dim))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
  model.add(Dense(256))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
  model.add(Dense(512))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
  model.add(Dense(14, activation='sigmoid'))
  model.add(Reshape((14,)))
  noise = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
  feature_gen = model(noise)
  return Model(noise, feature_gen)

def build_discriminator():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(512, input_dim=14))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
  model.add(Dropout(0.4))
  model.add(Dense(256))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
  model.add(Dropout(0.4))
  model.add(Dense(128))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
  model.add(Dropout(0.4))
  model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
  feature = Input(shape=(14,))
  validity = model(feature)
  return Model(feature, validity)


def build_gan(generator, discriminator):
  discriminator.trainable = False
  gan_input = Input(shape=(100,))
  generated_feature = generator(gan_input)
  gan_output = discriminator(generated_feature)
  gan = Model(gan_input, gan_output)
  gan.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.5))
  return gan
```

which yielded the following result:

```
Epoch 999/1000 [Dis loss: 0.3747815638780594, acc real: 78.91%, acc fake: 82.81%] [Gen loss: 2.687302589416504.
```

I did a lot of parameter tunning stuff. This accuracy is not acceptable, very low.
I would greatly appreciate any guidance or recommendations in this regard. Specifically, I am interested in alternative methods of data augmentation or any other techniques that can effectively expand a numeric dataset while preserving the integrity and patterns that already exist in the data.

Comment: Why is 87% a bad accuracy? What's that the accuracy of? The discriminator, or an overall model trained on GAN data plus original data?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo mistake. I updated questions and added code for GAN and its result too.

Comment: A GAN is adversarial. If the discriminator does a bad job at telling the real data from the fake, that could just mean that the generator is just very good at making plausible data.

Comment: Let consider, for each epoch real accuracy = 0% and fake accuracy= 100% and combine loss of discriminator and generator increases in each epoch 14, 18, 23,28 and so on. What it means ?